# run flow:install giving errors

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am using Flow type in react. On running command flow:install, i am getting following error for most of the dependencies

```
 Generating stubs for untyped dependencies...
 • @storybook/addons@^4.0.2
└> flow-typed\npm\@storybook\addons_vx.x.x.js
• gatsby-source-contentful@^2.0.9
└> flow-typed\npm\gatsby-source-contentful_vx.x.x.js
 !! No flow@v0.86.0-compatible libdefs found in flow-typed for the above untyped dependencies !!
```

Node version - 10.13.0
npm version - 6.4.1

Flow dependencies

```
 "flow-bin": "^0.86.0",
 "flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
```

Please help what is wrong here.

Comment: I got the answer. We can leave with this error, its just few packages are not covered in libdef files. Reference - https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/issues/527

Comment: Can you reply to your own question as you found the answer yourself and check it please ?